# how to open viewcontroller in code

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

How to go to viewcontroller after certain actions, like here:

```
func requestForAccessToken(authorizationCode: String) {

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
                let accessToken = response.object(forKey: "access_token")!
                UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: "LIAccessToken")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                ///here...
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
//                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    let secondViewController: LoginViewController = LoginViewController()
                    self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

            }
        }

    }
```

I create vc in storyboard and make vc class file. Maybe I must make something other.

Comment: You have to create the segue in Interface Builder.

Comment: Did you try this? `let secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name:"LoginViewController", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController`

Comment: @Santosh no, m trying now. I have one more question i must set identifier in storyboard id ? and after make `self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creatung a `viewController` in `storyboard` then you have to instantiate it with storyboard. Try this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
    let secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name:"LoginViewController", bundle: nil.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginV‌​iewController") as? LoginViewController
    self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Hoping that you have named your storyboard as `LoginViewController` and provided with `storyboardID` as `LoginViewController`

Comment: i get error on breakpoint with `let secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name:"LoginViewController", bundle: nil.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginV‌​iewController") as? LoginViewController`

Comment: `15  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010510068d start + 1
 16  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: Glad, it helped you!